# TypeScript errors when building because I import extracted .graphql files and the type can't be resolved

Tags: typescript, vue.js, graphql

I have the following file `@/graphql/mutations.graphql` containing:

```
mutation addCharacterToUser($userId: ID!, $characterId: ID!) {
    addCharacterToUser(userId: $userId, characterId: $characterId) {
        characterIds
    }
}

mutation newCharacter ($name: String!, $age: Int!) {
    newCharacter(character: {name: $name, age: $age}) {
        id
    }
}
```

Now I am using it in one of my Vue.js components (I use TypeScript with Vue.js).
However when I run `npm run build` I receive the following error:

```
 error  in C:/Development/Project/src/components/character/CharacterCreationDialog.vue

ERROR in C:/Development/Project/src/components/character/CharacterCreationDialog.vue(59,50):
59:50 Cannot find module '@/graphql/character/mutations.graphql' or its corresponding type declarations.
    57 | <script lang="ts">
    58 | import Vue from 'vue'
  > 59 | import { addCharacterToUser, newCharacter } from '@/graphql/character/mutations.graphql'
       |                                                  ^
    60 | 
    61 | export default Vue.extend({
    62 |   name: 'CharacterCreationDialog',
```

I researched some things but I can't really understand what the issue is. I have very little experience with TypeScript.

Comment: It sounds like you have to add babel loader to support load gql file

Answer (score 0):

It seems you do not have the required module `@/graphql/character/mutations.graphql` installed in your project workspace. Can you try checking if you might my missing the module?

Check your dependencies in `package.json` and ensure you can run `npm install` with no errors.

Comment: what module should I miss? Using `vue ui` the whole dependency management is somewhat automated so I have no real overview

Comment: Can you try running `npm list` to see what dependencies / modues are installed in your workspace and possibly pipe that to a grep for `graphql`? 
Using this code `npm list | grep 'graphql'`

Comment: `graphql/character/mutations.graphql` is from my project it's not a installed dependency